# Is it possible to use reduce in a callback function?

Tags: reason, reason-react

I have this simple component

```
let component = ReasonReact.statelessComponent("Input");

let make = (~name, ~onChange, ~value, _children) => {
    ...component,
    render: (_self) =>
        <input
            name=name
            onChange={(_) => {
              onChange(name, "change")
            }}
            value=value />
};
```

and I'm trying to use it like this

```
<Input
    name="
    placeholder="Your email"
    onChange={self.reduce((name, value) => Change(name, value))}
    label=""
    value={self.state.email} />
```

But I get this error on the `onChange` line

```
This is:
    ReasonReact.Callback.t(string) (defined as (string) => unit)
  But somewhere wanted:
    (string, string) => unit

  The incompatible parts:
    unit
    vs
    (string) => unit
```

I think I understand the error, but I have no idea to to fix it. I also to define `onChange` like this

```
onChange={(name, value) => self.reduce((_, _) => Change(name, value))}
```

but this time I get

```
This is:
    ReasonReact.Callback.t('a) (defined as ('a) => unit)
  But somewhere wanted:
    unit
```

Do you have an idea how to fix it ? Is it possible to call `reduce` inside another callback function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce` takes a 1-ary function and returns a 1-ary function, but your `onChange` is expected to be a 2-ary function. Since you seem to control both sides of this, the simplest fix is to just use a tuple:

Definition:

```
onChange={self.reduce(((name, value)) => Change(name, value))}
```

Application:

```
onChange={(_) => {
  onChange((name, "change"))
}}
```

Alternatively, if you don't control how the callback is used, you can wrap it in another function like you tried to, but since `reduce` returns a function you have to explicitly call it:

```
onChange={(name, value) => self.reduce(() => Change(name, value))()}
```

Note: The argument you pass to *the callback returned by* `reduce` is the same argument that will be passed to *the callback passed to* `reduce`, in this case just `()`. But `value => self.reduce(val => Action(val))(value)` is therefore equivalent to just doing `self.reduce(val => Action(val))`.